# .NET Parallel processing with UDP input

Tags: .net, algorithm, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, udpclient

I am pondering about how to parallelize my data processing in my application. Let me explain how the model and data flow is structured:

**Model:**

- List of Type DataType1
- Each DataType1 contains a List of DataType2
- Each DataType2 contains a class of DataType3
- Each DataType3 contains a list of int

**Data flow:**

- Input: UDP data (implemented with asynchronous udpclient)
- From UDP class an event is raised to main class (with message)
  Info: Each message contains information of DataType1 and DataType2 and more
- Each message gets pushed into DataType3's list of int values
- IF the list of int values reached a specified amount of values:

  - Raise event to call an algorithm which produces a result

Let's assume I have 500 elements of DataType1 (each result refers to an element of DataType1), it takes nearly 40 seconds until the processing is finished.

I would like to know how I should try (if possible) to transform that data flow into a parallel one, which would be able to be done in 3-5 seconds, for example? I tried to work with the Task Parallel Library, but without any gain.

I would appreciate any input regarding this task, I am stuck.

**EDIT:**

@svick: thanks for your response. I try to formulate some more details of my construction.
Below you find some pieces of source code. As you see, I am using a lot of callback constructions, different classes, lists, et cetera. Answering your questions 2 and 3 first:
I am currently using a dual-core processor, and I won't have any chance probably to get
to use anything with better performance. The reason I was looking toward a gain in performance
was due to the hope that my source code could be optimized toward it. 
When I was using the Task Parallel Library, I constructed an actionblock of a special type
and called Post instead of my previous code, which called a method that executed the same code
as before (just hoping that under the hood it is done in parallel with tasks, etc.).
(you find the lines in my source code below ("I tried"))
Once the data limit is reached, a chain of callbacks are raised. Each DataType1 is finished,
once one of his DataType2 elements has a filled stack. Then an algorithm is started to 
compare the different stacks. 
This is done for each DataType1 element, thus I was hoping to get it done in parallel in some way.

Here you find some snippets of code. 
p.s.: I tried to simulate data via a second application in that I built a list of nearly 4000 message entries, that are sent via udp in a foreach loop to my application. (using the same port on the same machine).

Model classes (each class forwards a callback to its upper class):

**CollectData:**

```
 public CollectData(proc proc)
{
    _proc = proc;
    PoolClass.lstDataType1 = new List<DataType1>();

}

public void Init(List<DataType1> lstDT1, List<DataType2> lstDT2)
{
        foreach (DataType1 dt1Data in lstDT1)
        {
            DataType1 dt1 = new DataType1(dt1ID, lstDT2, IncRec);
            PoolClass.lstDataType1.Add(dt1);

        }


}

delegate void ProcCallback(int dtID);
private void ProcRec(int dtID)
{
    if (_proc != null)
    {
        _proc(dtID);
    }

}

public void Push(Message message)
{
     PoolClass.lstDataType1.Where(t => t.dtId == message.DT1ID).FirstOrDefault().lstDataType2.Where(d => d.Id == message.DT2ID).FirstOrDefault().Stack.Push(message);
}
```

**DataType1:**

```
 public class DataType1
        {
            public int dtId;
            public List<DataType2> lstDataType2;

            public DataType1(int tdt1ID, List<DataType2> lstDT2, incRec incRec)
            {
                foreach (DataType2 dt2 in list)
                {
                    DataType2 dt2 = new DataType2(DataLimitReached);
                    lstDataType2.Add(dt2);
                }
            }


  delegate void DataLimitReachedCallback();
  private void DataLimitReached()
    {
        _proc(dt1ID);

    }
}
```

**DataType2:**

```
public class DataType2
{   
  public DataType3 Stack;
  Stack = new DataType3(DataLimitReached);

   delegate void DataLimitReachedCallback();
        private void DataLimitReached()
        {
            if (_DataLimitReached != null)
            {
                _DataLimitReached();
            }

        }   
}
```

**DataType3:**

```
public class DataType3
{
     public delegate void DataLimitReached();
     public DataLimitReached _DataLimitReached;

     public DataType3[] arrData;

     public DataStack(DataLimitReached DataLimitReached)
     {
          _DataLimitReached = DataLimitReached;
     }

     public void Push(Message message)
    {
        //add message to arrData
        //check if data limit was reached, build average
        if (_DataLimitReached != null)
        {
            _DataLimitReached();
        }
    }


}
```

**Main:**

```
Server udpServer = new Server(port);
this.udpServer.OnMessage += new Server.DelegateMessageReceived(udpServer_OnMessage);

Module module = new Module();
module.Init();
module.OnProcData += new Module.RecHandler(module_OnProcData);

void udpServer_OnMessage(Message message)
{
    procMessage(message);

}

private void procMessage(Message message)
{
    module.setData(message);
    //I tried: this.actionBlock.Post(message);
}

 void module_OnProcData(Module m, ModuleEventArgs e)
{
  //log data result or put to listbox
}

public class PoolClass
{
      public static List<DataType1> lstDataType1;
}
```

**Module:**

```
public CollectData cData;

public void Init()
{
    cData = new CollectData(Proc);

    List<DataType2> lstDT2 = new List<DataType2>;

    cData.Init(lstDT2);

}

public void setData(Message message)
{
    cData.Push(message);
}       


delegate void ProcCallback(int dtID);
private void Proc(int dtID)
{
    DoCalculation(dtID);
    //I tried: this.actionBlock.Post(dtID);
}

private void RaiseProcEvent(ModuleEventArgs e)
{
    if (OnProcData != null)
    {
        OnProcData(this, e);
    }

}

public void DoCalculation(int DT1Id)
{
   //do calculation
   RaiseProcEvent(e);
}
```

**UDP:**

```
public class Server

public delegate void DelegateMessageReceived(Message message);

Task.Run(async () =>
{
    using (var udpClient = new UdpClient())
    {
        udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        udpClient.Client.Bind(localpt);

        while (true)
        {
            if (udpClient.Available > 0)
            {
                var receiveBytes = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();
                if (receiveBytes.Buffer.Length <= 0)
                    return;
                Message message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes.Buffer));


                if (OnMessage != null)
                {
                   OnMessage(message);
                }
                //I tried:  this.actionBlock.Post(message);
            }
        }
    }
});

}
```

Thanks

Comment: 1. From your description, it's not clear to me what's actually happening. Could you include code demonstrating how the data flow works? 2. What makes you think you can achieve 10x speedup? Do you have a machine with more than 10 cores? 3. Could you describe what exactly did you try?

Comment: I tried to answer your questions in the answer below, I am not able to put that much of information into a comment, I hope it was the appropriate way. (wondering about the downvote)

Comment: Updates to your question should be done by editing the question, not adding an *answer*.

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry about it, didn't know, will keep in mind for the next time, thanks.